# How to handle rejections in Bluebird without breaking a Promise chain?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, bluebird

Let's say I'm building a typical RSS-reader. I'm parsing several feeds and write all their episodes to DB:

```
const processEpisode = (episode)=>
  fetchMetadata(episode)
  .then(parseMetadata)
  .then(writeToDb)

const processFeed = (feed)=>
  fetchEpisodes(feed) // returns [Episode]
  .map(processEpisode,  { concurrency: 3 })

// main
getFeeds() // returns [Feed]
.map(processFeed, { concurrency: 3 })
.catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

1. We get all the feeds
2. For each feed emit `processFeed()`
3. For each episode emit `processEpisode()` from `processFeed()`

However, if `fetchMetadata(episode)` for some episode for some feed throws a rejection, **all** the chain is broken and immediately falls into global `.catch(err=> console.log(err))`.

In normal situation we need to do something with unprocessed episode, but the least should be processed normally. One solution is to wrap `processEpisode()` in an outer Promise and handle in-place.

```
const processEpisode = (episode)=>
  new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    fetchMetadata(episode)
    .then(parseMetadata)
    .then(writeToDb)
    .then((result)=> resolve(result))
    .catch((err)=> {
      // something bad happened
      // process and error, but resolve a fullfilled Promise!
      resolve(true)
    })
  })
```

However, I suppose it's an obvious anti-pattern. And if after `processEpisode()` there is another element in higher level Promise chain, it will fail 'cause `processEpisode` will resolve `true` instead of real result.

Is there an elegant way to solve such problems? I've looking through [`finally`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) statement in Bluebird, but I'm not sure it's the best way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put a `.catch()` handler directly on `processFeed()` so you can process the rejection locally and turn it into a resolved promise which will allow everything else to continue:

```
// main
getFeeds() // returns [Feed]
.map(function(item, index, length) {
    return processFeed(item, index, length).catch(function(reason) {
       // do whatever you want to here, this will "handle" the rejection
       //   and turn it into a resolved promise
       // whatever you return here will become the resolved value
    });
}, { concurrency: 3 })
.catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

Note: You don't need the extra wrapping promise.  Adding a `.catch()` handler and returning a normal value from the `.catch()` handler will turn the rejected promise into a resolved promise as the rejection is considered "handled" at this point.  Whatever value you return from the `.catch()` handler becomes the resolved value of the parent promise.

A `.catch()` handler will only keep the promise rejected if it returns a rejected promise or throws.

Comment: Tried this just before your comment, and it worked :) Thank you for confirmation. Marking this as solved.